# Use of variables withing singlequotes, CSH

Tags: shell-script, csh

I have a short script meant to do some server maintinence, but I can't for the life of my figure out how to properly use variables within my script, Here's a code sample to make it more clear:

```
--members "fmcfsv05a:aggr1_fmcfs05n01a_L" "businessgroup=='MDO'&&project==' $i '&&qslot=='Martini'"
```

In this sample, the "$i" is my variable, yet the output still yeilds this:

```
--members "fmcfsv05a:aggr1_fmcfs05n01a_L" "businessgroup=='MDO'&&project==' $i '&&qslot=='Martini'"
```

when ran with -v. Any ideas on how to force variables within single quotes?

Comment: recommendation: use sh/ksh/bash for scripts. Csh has inconsistencies in command line parsing in different points, and it leads to lengthy and frustrating debugging

Comment: What @mpez0 said. I learned that the lengthy and frustrating way.

Answer (score 0):

Without going into the details why you should [avoid CSH](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/), this ran fine here:

```
$ cat test.csh 
set i="$1"
/bin/echo --members "fmcfsv05a:aggr1_fmcfs05n01a_L" "businessgroup=='MDO'&&project==' $i '&&qslot=='Martini'"

$ csh test.csh foo
--members fmcfsv05a:aggr1_fmcfs05n01a_L businessgroup=='MDO'&&project==' foo '&&qslot=='Martini'

$ dpkg-query -W csh
csh     20110502-2.1
```